# How did they animate the light in Akira?

Tags: akira

Akira is known for pioneering many animation techniques. My questions is pretty specific, though: I'm wondering exactly how they photographed the various glows and lights in the dark and night scenes. I know the bright white lights (e.g. motorcycle headlights) were hand animated using cut-out masks over light tables. But the additive smears (e.g. the motorcycle tail lights) don't seem to use that technique. And even for the light table shots -- how did they combine those with the rest of the frame photographically?  What was the compositing technique for traditional film photographed cel animation?

Comment: Related question with answers here: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/42151/how-this-glow-effect-was-created-in-cel-shaded-anime